# $C^k(M,C^k(N,L))$ coincides with $C^k(M\times N,L)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry, reference-request

Let $k\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{\infty\}\cup\{\omega\}$, and $M,N,L$ be $C^k$-manifolds.

Define the space $C^k(M,C^k(N,L))$ of $C^k$ function from $M$ to the space of $C^k$-function from $N$ to $L$, namely $F\in C^k(M,C^k(N,L))$ means that $F(m)\in C^k(N,L)$. Hence, one can identify $F$ to a map $f\colon M\times N\to L$, by defining $$f(m,n):=F(m)(n),$$
which induces a map $\Phi\colon C^k(M,C^k(N,L))\to C^k(M\times N,L).$

Conversely a map $f\in C^k(M\times N,L)$ can be seen as a map $F\colon M\to C^k(N,L)$ denoting $$F(m):=f(m,\cdot)\colon N\to L,$$
which induces a map $\Psi\colon C^k(M\times N,L)\to C^k(M,C^k(N,L)).$

Clearly, this correspondence is bijective: indeed,
\begin{align}
\Psi\circ\Phi=&\mathrm{Id}_{C^k(M,C^k(N,L))}\\
\Phi\circ\Psi=&\mathrm{Id}_{C^k(M\times N,L)}
\end{align}

The motivation for my question is way less general: in fact, I have a smooth path $\gamma$ in $C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and I wolud like to prove that it can be seen as a smooth map in $C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^{n+1})$.

I think I have already solved my problem: since the tangent map $\gamma'(t)$ has to be a linear bounded map from $\mathbb R\to C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$, and the map associating to $t$ the derivative of the smooth map $\gamma(t)$ does the job, and I think the same argument holds for any $k$ and for any $C^k$-manifolds.

However, I could not find a source, that is why I decided to ask the question anyway.

***EDIT:*** I made a mistake. In fact, as it is defined, the map $\Psi$ send a function $f\in C^k(M\times N,L)$ to $C^k(M,C^{k-1}(N,L))$, because its derivative at $x\in M$ would be the linear map
$$A_x=\frac{\partial}{\partial y} f(x,\cdot)\colon N\to L,$$
which is $C^{k-1}$ and not $C^k$.

It should be true for $k=\infty$, someone has an idea for $k=\omega$?

Comment: What's the topology you put on $C^k(A,B)$?

Comment: For $k\in\mathbb{N}$ (resp. $k=\infty$) the one induced by the family of $C^k$-norms (resp. $C^j$-seminorms, for $j\in\mathbb{N}$) on compact subsets, for the analytic case, I am tempted to say the one induced by the inclusion in $C^\infty$, but I am not sure it is the right one.

Comment: What does it mean for a function $f : M \to C^k(N, L)$ to be $C^k$?

Comment: Let $(X,\|\cdot\|_X)$, $(Y,\|\cdot\|_Y)$ be two Banach spaces. The map $f\colon X\to Y$ admits a derivative at $x\in X$ if there exists a bounded linear function $A_x\colon X\to Y$ such that $\|f(x+h)-f(x)-A_x h\|_Y=o(\|h\|_X)$. The map $f\in C^1(X,Y)$ if $A_\bullet\colon X\to L(X,Y)$ is continuous, for $L(X,Y)$ the space of bounded linear function from $X$ to $Y$ endowed with the operator norm, that is $\|F\|_{L(X,Y)}=\sup_{x\in X}\frac{\|F(x)\|_Y}{\|x\|_X}.$ Recursively, the first derivative of $f$ is a map between the Banach spaces $X$ and $L(X,Y)$: $f\in C^2(X,Y)\iff A\in C^1(X,L(X,Y)$.